# Creating a "virtual" dir that wraps two (external) drives

Tags: macos, disk-utility, filesystem, folders, raid

I was wondering if MacOS Mojave (the most recent version I can be on due to some very expensive 32 bit applications) has a way to set up a "virtual" dir, or even virtual drive, that combines two or more external drives and surfaces them as if they're one directory/drive.

E.g. something that lets me say "create a virtual dir/drive called `audio data`" (that *isn't* JBOD/RAID0) and then specify two (or more) external SSDs such that the content of that dir/drive is the combined content of the solid state drives. If one has dirs `Pro Logic data` and `Cubase data` and the other has dirs `Kontakt` and `Samples`, then I'd like a single virtual dir/drive that shows:

```
--- data
 |--- Cubase Data
 |--- Kontakt
 |--- Pro Logic Data
 |--- Samples
```

When both SSD are connected, or if one of them's not connected, show

```
--- data
 |--- Cubase Data
 |--- Pro Logic Data
```

or

```
--- data
 |--- Kontakt
 |--- Samples
```

depending on which drive's still accessible. Or a flatout empty dir/drive if nothing's connected.

With the explicit intent that if the SSDs that house dirs that some applications rely on aren't connected, then yes: those applications will throw errors. That's fine, and expected. I just want something that lets me surface a ton of data spread over multiple drives as a single dir/drive when they're all connected, with each SSD being "just a drive" that can also be connected to any random other computer that knows how to read/write the SSD's filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

To create a combined directory, run

```
find /path/to/volume1 /path/to/volume2 -type d -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 \
    -exec ln -s '{}' '/path/to/virtualfolder/' \;
```

This will not take care of any duplicates, it will also not create the virtual folder (do this before running `find`).